# Google fusion tables: Fill in lon/lat columns via geocoded address

Tags: google-maps, google

I have a list of 100 companies that I want to geocode. I have all of their addresses but none of their lon/lat coordinates.

I have three columns related to location:

1. Address
2. Longitude
3. Latitude

Is it possible that when file->geocode is clicked (relating to the address column) that it fills in the longitude and latitude columns with the coordinates? I can then read these columns from there on in avoiding the need to geocode again.

Update

On further research it's seems I have to store the geocoded result in a database... not fusion tables as it doesn't seem possible with how I want it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
<strike>That's not possible with google because you are not allowed by the license to store the geocoding results (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits)</strike> (see comments)

One alternative option is to use the [CloudMade](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects) Geocoding based on OpenStreetMap data. It has a Python API that you can use to get the coordinates, than you can easily output a simple delimited text file to be imported into fusion tables.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I can see it doesn't say anything about storing them, just that the geocoded results need to be used with a Google Map, which it will be. Since asking the question it becoming more and more obvious that a fusion table is the right way to go.

Comment: Rob, I'm sorry for my mistake, after a better reading of the license I found this: "Geocoding is a time and resource intensive task. Whenever possible, pre-geocode known addresses..and store your results in a temporary cache".

Comment: Great, it's good to know as it points out it's possible. Just need to find out how to do it!